# Binding multiple pthreads, each to the same member function of a different object from the same class

Tags: pthreads, member-functions

I have bound multiple pthreads to independent member function of independent objects from the same class.

I had to use of a static member function as a helper since it is not possible to bind a member function directly to a pthread in C++; however, my application behaves strangely and I am suspicious to the use of this static function, since this static function is shared between all objects of the same class.

Is this type of usage right? Is there any alternative solution?

I appreciate to hear any guidance.

```
class Region
{
public:

    Region();

    void Init();

    void Push_Tuple(int int_value, float float_value, bool tuple_source);

    static void *Read_Tuple_R_Process_S_Update_helper(void *context)
    {
        return ((Region *)context)->Read_Tuple_R_Process_S_Update();
    }
    void* Read_Tuple_R_Process_S_Update();

    static void *Read_Tuple_S_Process_R_Update_helper(void *context)
    {
        return ((Region *)context)->Read_Tuple_S_Process_R_Update();
    }   
    void* Read_Tuple_S_Process_R_Update();
};

int main(){

    Region regions[THREAD_COUNT*2]; 

    for(int i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT*2; i++){
        regions[i].Init();
    }

    pthread_t thread_ID[THREAD_COUNT*2];
    void* exit_status;

    for(int i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread_ID[i], NULL, &Region::Read_Tuple_R_Process_S_Update_helper, &regions[i]);
    }

    for(int i=THREAD_COUNT; i < THREAD_COUNT*2; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread_ID[i], NULL, &Region::Read_Tuple_S_Process_R_Update_helper, &regions[i]);
    }   

    for(int i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT*2; i++){
        pthread_join(thread_ID[i], &exit_status);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into Boost or C++11 threads? Both simplify thread creation and binding to class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was suspected to the binding that I described, it was not the source of my problem and it works correctly. 
The problem was waiting while loops which were affected by optimizer! Using volatile keyword solved my problem.